# Change position closer to the right of rightBarButtonItem in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

This is my code

```
- (void)createCustomBtnRightBar:(UIImage *)buttonImage
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    if (buttonImage != nil) {
        [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 45, 33);
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, -10);
    } else {
        [button setTitle:@"Add New Pal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 24);
        [button.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    }

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickBtnSendClip:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    //create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
}
```

[image]

When Change width to 200

[image]

When add `button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0);`

[image]

> In all these cases, the area of the right can not move

I need something like this.

[image]

I even tried this

```
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
customBarItem.customView = button;
```

but does crash

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Fixed and flexible space items not allowed as individual navigation bar button item. Please use the rightBarButtonItems (that's plural) property.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001132a2e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000112d19deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001132a2d9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x000000011156d560 -[UINavigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:animated:] + 131
    4   sdsd sdsdsd                         0x000000010e042dd3 -[SendClipViewController createCustomBtnRightBar:] + 1475
```

> Worked perfect before when I was the button bar direct from the story board and space on the right was smaller (as I need).

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use .Fixed Space to achieve this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
negativeSpacer.width = -10;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[negativeSpacer, customBarItem];
```

Comment: Use `self.navigationController.view.layoutMargins.right` for actual margin

Comment: Does this work for people? It doesn't work for me.. My barButtonItem is a `UIBarButtonItem` initialised from a `customView`.. I can set it to `10`, and it will be moved 10 to the left, but if I set it to `-10`, then nothing happens, as if it was `0`.

Comment: Seems like this stopped working in iOS 11. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80075