# Aligning the rightBarButtonItem to rightmost side?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Trying to get the barButton to right side so that the borders seem attached to the right.

I tried using a fixed sized spacer but that doesn't help with what I am trying to achieve I guess, since I want it to apply to every screen size available.

Does anyone have a way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get rid of the space on the right side of a UINavigationBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106306/get-rid-of-the-space-on-the-right-side-of-a-uinavigationbar)

Comment: Something like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775351/change-position-closer-to-the-right-of-rightbarbuttonitem-in-uinavigationbar?

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai Yeah, this is a duplicate, thanks.

Comment: @jose920405 No, tried negative fixed sized spacers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was answered before in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106306/get-rid-of-the-space-on-the-right-side-of-a-uinavigationbar)

Thanks to Zhi-Wei Cai for pointing it out.